# Setting up pglogical over ssh tunnel, connection reset by peer

Tags: postgresql, pglogical

I am setting up a pglogical replication between an on-premise PostgreSQL 10.14 (publisher and AWS RDS Postgresql 10.16 (subscriber), but after setting up a subscription, I only get to connection resets. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

**Network setup:**

```
On-premise postgres < jumphost > <-- ssh tunnel --> AWS RDS
internal-ip                          10.2.0.8       db01.some.tld
```

I have verified that the ssh tunnel is working:

- I can connect to the on-premise postgres from AWS using psql connecting to the tunnel
- I can even connect to the on-premise postgres from AWS RDS when using postgres_fwd

**Pglogical setup:**
on-premise:

- create node with dsn `host=10.2.0.8 dbname=... user=... password=...`

AWS:

- create node with dsn `host=db01.some.tld dbname=... user=... password=...`
- create subscription with dsn `host=10.2.0.8 dbname=... user=... password=...`

Once that is done:

- pglogical processes are running on both the provider and subscriber
- but I get to the following **errors**:
  AWS:

> LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
> LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction

On-premise:

> LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction

I have tried fiddling around with logging parameters, but couldn't get to anything useful. Similarly I couldn't get anything helpful from the ssh tunnel logs.

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. In this case:

The connection was fine. However, there was an issue with the schema of one table on the replica, causing the replication to die.